# Last order details are displaying duplicate values for configurable products

Tags: magento, checkout

I have added a simple code to track each purchase on the site. All products have different types of rules based on categories to subtract a predefined percent of amount of product price.

But when there are configurable products in the cart then it is displaying me both products, original product price and the price of the selected option for the product details in the order detail.
If I have a lipstick in my cart and the color I selected is "RED" then lipstick price will change. But it is displaying me the original lipstick price as well as the red lipstick price in the order details.

I have added the code on order success page.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
     ->setOrder('created_at','DESC')
     ->setPageSize(1)
     ->setCurPage(1);
$orderId = $orders->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{
            $pid = $item->getProductId();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
        $_finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();

        echo $price = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_finalPrice,true,false);
                // Some Code
}
```

I have also tried

```
$tempmain = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId());
    $temp = $tempmain->getAllItems();

    $total = $tempmain->getGrandTotal();
    foreach ($temp as $itemId => $item)
    {
              $pid = $item->getProductId();
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);
            $_finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();

            echo $price = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_finalPrice,true,false);
                    // Some Code
        }
```

With the same results.

How to get only "RED" lipstick price in Order details?

Thanks in advance.

This is the details for all the availabel lipstick and their values:
[image]
when I select "Tango" as the color for lipstick on front end:
[image]
I am getting the Price of both products on success page:
[image]
Here is the Order Details Screen shot:
[image]

Comment: You should not request product price data from order items. Rather, get the data from the order items. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296719/magento-get-the-quantity-in-cart-for-a-given-product/8301170#8301170

Comment: hello benmarks, thanks for your reply. but I can't understand what should I do to get only the data of the "RED LIPSTICK"..

Comment: Have a look in the `sales_flat_order_item` table and refer to my answer I linked above.

Comment: Hi bemarks. Thanks for your link, I removed parent products from configurable and grouped products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In frontoffice, when a customer add a configurable produt in his cart and order it, you'll see (in Database) 2 lines (2 quote_items and 2 order_item).

It's normal because magento needs to store the configurable product and the linked simple produt corresponding to the user selection (and linked to the master configurable product).

When displaying order details, Magento handles that difference by checking if a product has a parent id. You can do the same to ignore some order_item :

```
foreach($items as $item){
    if ($item->getParentProductId() {
         continue; // ignoring simple product associated to master order item (configurable)
    }
    // your code

}
```

Comment: Hi. Bixi. Thanks for Reply. This helped me Removing parent product from order items. Now Everything works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm NOT 100% sure what your tying to do, but if you are on the order success page then this is the way to retrive the current order info (get the the last order for the db may not always be the current order on the success  page if two user make a purchase millisecond apart)

Try adding this to Success.phtml

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();


foreach($items as $item){
  if ($item->getParentItem()) {
       continue;
  }
  echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getPrice(),true,false); 
}
```

Comment: Hi R.S. Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried this code but it is displaying the same result. I am getting original lipstick price as well as red lipstick price. :(
And Do you have any other idea for getting order details for placed order.

Comment: What price does it show on your order confirmation email? What do you mean by showing original lipstick as well as red lipstick price? The  code above should only show one price. You may want to add a screen shot of the success page above and your order confirmation email

Comment: Hello R.S. I have added screen shots for the problem. Can you give me any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You have two items in your cart right? Take a look at sales_flat_order* db table. Also add $item->getName() in the code above and `<br>` tags and your order confirmation email.

Comment: no. I have only one item in my cart. I have attached the order detail screen shot at the end. you can see that there is only one product in order.

Comment: How many time do you have "Product Price is : ..." in your foreach loop? Do a print_r($order->getItemsCollection()) and see how may items you have

Comment: I have tried to display product name on success page. and it is displaying both the names.
Name : MINERAL LIPSTICK
Name : MINERAL LIPSTICK-Tango

Comment: Did you take a look @ sales_flat_order_item to see how many items is on that order? Do you have a lot of custom module installed?